# Find the last record in Access Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an items table to which I am going to add a form to search and do maintenance on the records in the table. One thing I must have missed was making the ItemNumber (the PK) a number datatype instead of an autonumber. I now have thousands of records in other tables referencing these ItemNumbers but I need a way to essentially make the number a "fake" autonumber. So when the user goes to create a new item, the textbox that will contain the itemnumber will need to look at if it is a new record if so, see what the next number needs to be. Can someone show a sample of the VBA or macro that needs to run for this to work?

Note: I do have the field indexed so that it will notify the user if the number has already been used.
Access 2016

Comment: Can't you just make the field an autonumber?  FWIW, there's several ways to do this with SQL - `SELECT Max(ItemNumber) FROM Table` or `SELECT TOP 1 ItemNumber FROM Table ORDER BY ItemNumber DESC`, etc.

Comment: @Comintern, I would like to make it an autonumber but it would end up changing the PK that is referenced in many other places, making a bunch of data incorrect and invalid. I will try writing a query and making the next number based on the result of that query. Thanks, didn't even think of that.

Comment: So turn cascade updates on first.

Comment: From what I have tried, I would have to delete the field and then recreate it as an autonumber since you can't change the datatype to autonumber once it is set to number. Either that or I'd have to create a new table and copy the data other than the item number into it. Do you know a way around this?

Comment: Recreate the table - insert dummy records to fill in all the non-sequential values, create a new table with the same fields (with an autonumber PK), insert from the old table into the new table in PK order, then delete the dummy records. That should maintain your key relationships.

Comment: Database 101: Never allow users to manage PKs! In dev sandbox, consider 1) adding the AutoNumber field keeping original, 2) temporarily break relationships, 3) update all tables FKs to new autonumber with `WHERE` clause set to original, 4) re-establish relationships, 5) delete original. See why database design is a very crucial step in the lifecycle!

Comment: @KScott Are looking for when a user will create new record, then `ItemNumber` field will generate number (max number + 1) automatically.

Comment: @Parfait I don't want the user to manage the PK. I want a way to fix the original mistake. I'm looking long-term: if I leave the position, I know how to make sure the PK isn't compromised but the next employee may not. So I'm looking for a fix that will be in a textbox that is invisible to the user but will automatically calculate the next PK. All without compromising the current design and the current data in the system.

Comment: @harun24hr Yes that is correct. I may just end up redesigning the table. It will lead to pretty much recreating a bunch of other tables. It's not ideal since this table is the child most and 13 other tables rely on it's data but I think it's the only sure-fire way to ensure no problems with the identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you have a table with unique PK, regular Number data type and you want to have auto numbering feature. If so, it's easy to change data type to Autonumber. You cannot insert any desired value into autonumber field in Table Designer, but you can do it using SQL `INSERT`. So, just create new table with Autonumber data type, copy all records from old table to new one using query, including PK data, re-link existing 13 tables to new table, drop old table and rename new one. No other changes will be required in other tables, they will keep the same references to the table with auto numbering. After this operation compact and repair the database, it will reset auto numbering to maximum inserted value.

Now in the form you'll be able to see and read new autonumber value immediately after changing any other field in the new record.

If you still want to create your own sequence and your database is multiuser, I'd recommend to implement it as recommended by Microsoft: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/191253

But it would be better to use Autonumber as PK, you will have less problems in the future.